# EditText need 2 touches to get focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I now have waste a lot of time on this, and I feel the solution should be simple.

I have a ListView subclass that have rows that consist of an `EditText` and a `TextView`.
That `Activity` is the second one in my view hierarchy.
When I enter in it none of the `EditText` have focus and the keyboard don't shows up. (all good).
Now I touch an `EditText`, it gets focus, the keyboard shows up and at the same the `EditText` lose it's focus, at this point I touch the `EditText` again and now it get's and keep it's focus.

Any idea of what could get into conflict with each other to result in that behaviour?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this problem, but It so strange that I will post the solution in case some one have the same problem.

What is strange first. If I enter text in the EditText then commit my editing, the

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
```

is being call and at the end the `my ListView get updated for FREE`
If I add the following code into the Android manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".ConverterActivity" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

I've got almost the correct behaviour, but now the only missing thing is that I don't get updates anymore.
since updates were working before I was assuming that the above code was not working.
But I've decide to tell myself, if that code work, what would be the problem?
Well it's not updating look for a way to update your ListView and "voilà".

```
((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And now I'm wondering why was I getting update for Free in the first place...  ???

So if you got a good explanation for this, I would gladly change the green check to you.